# Place div text as input value

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to place a div text as an input value.
The thing is that the div text is given by an ui range slider...I can't get it to stick, it doesn't place the text as a value, here is what i have:

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/rkvbavto/1/)

**script:**

```
var sizes = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

$("#slider").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      animation:false,
      min: 0,
      max: 36,
      value: 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".rsize").text(sizes[ui.value]);
  }
});

$('#slider').change( function(){
   $('input').val($(".rsize").text());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var sizes = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

$("#slider").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      animation:false,
      min: 0,
      max: 36,
      value: 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".rsize").text(sizes[ui.value]);
      $('input').val($(".rsize").html());
  }
});
```

or use directly `$('input').val(sizes[ui.value]);`

Comment: Well,  all of your versions work and I look stupid cause I couldn't focus on such an easy task...all three of you get a +1 but according to the timeline, your answer was first so I will select it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a middle man place holder, just go right to the source:

```
var sizes = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

$("#slider").slider({
   orientation: "vertical",
   range: "min",
   animation:false,
   min: 0,
   max: 36,
   value: 0,
   slide: function(event, ui) {    
      $('.convert').val(sizes[ui.value]);
   }
});
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4wLstfd3/

Comment: Well,  all of your versions work and I look stupid cause I couldn't focus on such an easy task...all three of you get a +1 but according to the timeline, Ragnar's answer was first so I will select it. Thanks :)

Comment: Fair enough.  As long as you got a working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#slider").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      animation:false,
      min: 0,
      max: 36,
      value: 0,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
         $(".rsize").text(sizes[ui.value]); //you need?
         $('input').val(sizes[ui.value]);
      }
}
```

Comment: Well,  all of your versions work and I look stupid cause I couldn't focus on such an easy task...all three of you get a +1 but according to the timeline, Ragnar's answer was first so I will select it. Thanks :)